# Js result into HTML

Tags: javascript, nodejs, etherjs

Hello hope everybody is good ?
I need some help please ..

I run my JS file and it return in my console **with await function** = ***56***

How can i parse the return (56) into my HTML in a ***<div*** ?

This is my HTML :

```
<scrypt> async function getdata() { My scrypt here return 56 in console.log }</scrypt>
<button id="output" onclick="getdata()"style="height: 50px; width: 80px;" > Call it </button>
```

But when i click on ***Call it*** button, nothing is doing

Hope someone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You define `async` function.
I think, you need to use `await` keyword for some function calling; like this.

```
async function getdata() {

  // ... your scripts ...

  // someAsyncFunction() returns '56'.
  const result = await someAsyncFunction();

  const elm = document.createElement('div');
  const txt = document.createTextNode(result);
  elm.appendChild(txt);
}
```

Then, it seems there is a typo in your HTML.
I think `<scrypt>` shall be `<script>`.

**P.S.**
Thank you for adding your scripts.
I was mistaken that why '56' is written in console.
You may add '56' your html body with codes follows;

```
<body>

<script>
async function getdata() {

  const result = await someAsyncFunction();

  const elm = document.createElement('div');
  const txt = document.createTextNode(result);
  elm.appendChild(txt);

  document.body.appendChild(elm);
}

async function someAsyncFunction() {
  // Do not use console.log() function
  //console.log('56');

  return new Promise(
    (resolveFunc, rejectFunc) => {

      // You should call resolveFunc() when process successfully finished.
      if (true) {
        resolveFunc('56');
      }

      // If you want to treat error cases, you shall use try-catch statement at caller side, like follows;
      //
      // try {
      //   result = await someAsyncFunction();
      // }
      // catch (err) {
      //   alert(err);  // You will watch 'NG!!' message in alert-messagebox, not in console error log.
      // }
      //
      else {
        rejectFunc('NG!!');
      }
    }
  )
}
</script>

<div>
    <button id="output" onclick="getdata()"style="height: 50px; width: 80px;" > Call it </button>
</div>

</body>
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Thanks for answer acutally it return value 56 in my web console i wish it appear in my html body

Comment: Thank you for adding your scripts. I added new sample code which is suitable for your script. I wish it helps you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
  <body>

<script>
    async function getdata() {
const result = await someAsyncFunction();

const elm = document.createElement('div');
const txt = document.createTextNode(result);
elm.appendChild(txt);
  }





 async function someAsyncFunction() {
console.log('56');

 }
</script>
<div>
    <button id="output" onclick="getdata()"style="height: 50px; width: 80px;" > Call it </button>
</div>
</body>
```